# Use R to Create a New Decile Variable in a Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, r

I'm getting an error when trying to add a new field (of deciles of my income variable) to my shapefile within R. The error might be related to the fact that the input is a shapefile...

> UseMethod("mutate_") : no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to
>   an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons',
>   'Spatial')

```
require(rgdal)
#input data SES field
mydata<-readOGR("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\mydata.shp")
library(dplyr)
deciles = mutate(mydata, quantile_rank = ntile(mydata$income,10))
deciles
```

Answer (score 2):

What "they" didn't teach you about R is that instead of "mutate":

```
deciles = mutate(mydata, quantile_rank = ntile(mydata$income,10))
deciles
```

which only works sometimes, you can always create the new column directly:

```
deciles$quantile_rank = ntile(mydata$income,10)
deciles
```

Your input is an `sp` class "SpatialPolygons Data Frame", which has been read in from a shapefile. This behaves a bit like a data frame in most respects, but `dplyr`s functions do not support it.

Comment: It works!

mydata$quantile_rank = ntile(mydata$income,10)